# Mapping the selected value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 sets of data from two table , i need to join the table

table_ 1

```
id     qid     choice               
--------------------------
11     2020     Item 1
12     2020     Item 2
13     2020     Item 14
```

table_2

```
rid    qid     question
---------------------------
1001   2020    1.I love apple
1002   2020    2.I love orange
1003   2020    14.I hate lemon
```

Output

```
id    rid     qid     choice       question
-------------------------------------------------
11    1001    2020    Item 1      1.I love apple
12    1002    2020    Item 2      2.I love orange
13    1003    2020    Item 14     14.I hate lemon
```

The formate of the column "question" in table_2 must start with

```
1.XXXX , 2.XXXX , 14.XXXX until 20.XXXXXX
```

I think get the number before "." as the joining condition. But how to get the number or any other better solutions?

Comment: Something's wrong with the structure. Which column is the foreign key? qid? Shouldn't it be a unique value column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the data structure of your current tables. But for your current data structure you may use this tricky query (assuming the pattern of `table_1.choice` is always `Item XX`):

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.rid, t1.qid, t1.choice, t2.question
  FROM Table1 t1
  JOIN Table2 t2
    ON RIGHT(t1.choice, LENGTH(t1.choice) - 5) 
     = LEFT(t2.question, LOCATE('.',t2.question) - 1);
```

Output:

```
| ID |  RID |  QID |  CHOICE |        QUESTION |
|----|------|------|---------|-----------------|
| 11 | 1001 | 2020 |  Item 1 |  1.I love apple |
| 12 | 1002 | 2020 |  Item 2 | 2.I love orange |
| 13 | 1003 | 2020 | Item 14 | 14.I hate lemon |
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2fec9/3)

Comment: thank you very much 
If I put it into php, how to present the '.' , LOCATE('.',t2.question)

Comment: @user2210819 - Sorry I don't have knowledge of PHP. But you can search for this here.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.rid, t1.qid, t1.choice, t2.question
FROM table_1 t1
JOIN table_2 t2
On t1.qid = t2.qid
Order by t2.question
```