# Get the first character of the field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, substring

I have a table

table_1

```
col_1
----------
1.where
2.how
20.there
```

How can I get the number from the table when I select col_1 from the table

output

```
1
2
20
```

Use trim?

Comment: Use the [Split function](http://www.biitb.com/index.php/t-sql-split-function/)

Comment: I know you are asking this question because of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19019524/1369235). :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`LEFT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) function for that and [`LOCATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) to get the position of `.`:

```
SELECT LEFT(col_1, LOCATE('.',col_1) - 1) AS Num 
FROM Table1;
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5096/3)

Comment: @user2210819 - To remove dot `.` (it includes dot's position so to remove it)

Comment: @user2210819 - Regarding your previous [deleted question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19019524/1369235). I have found the current solution. If you wish I can share with you.

Comment: great , i need to undelete the question?

Comment: @user2210819 - Yeah. You should. It was not too bad question.

Answer (score 1):

use `SUBSTRING(col_1, 1,  INSTR(col_1, ".") - 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in mysql:

```
select substring(col_1,1,locate(".",col_1)-1) from table_1
```